# laravel blade empty page

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

This is my route

```
Route::get('login', function(){
    return View::make('admins.login');
});
```

This is my `admins/login.blade.php`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'admins.store', 'class' => 'loginClass')) }}
<ul>
    <li>
        {{ Form::text('username', '', array('placeholder' => 'Username'))}}
        <span>test</span>
    </li>
</ul>

{{ Form::close() }}
@stop

</body>
</html>
```

The result is empty page. However, when the change the `admins/login.blade.php` to:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
TEST TEST TEST
</body>
</html>
```

I got `TEST TEST TEST` printed in the browser.

what am I missing wrong please?

Comment: Code looks fine, what if you remove loginClass?

Comment: @ErikÅstrand the same, empty page

Comment: I see that you have `@stop`, but no accompanying `@section`. Try taking that out; what appears then?

Comment: @ChrisForrence Yes that works :) many thanks, type an answer to accept it please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your blade page includes the `@stop` within it, but there's no accompanying `@section` tag.

It should look like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'admins.store', 'class' => 'loginClass')) }}
<ul>
    <li>
        {{ Form::text('username', '', array('placeholder' => 'Username'))}}
        <span>test</span>
    </li>
</ul>

{{ Form::close() }}

</body>
</html>
```